# Why aren't public keys allowed to contain certain alphanumeric characters?

Tags: publickey, solana-keygen

This might seem petty, but I noticed that the following characters do not exist inside of public keys and are not allowed to be used when performing `solana-keygen grind`. I'm interested in what the background story is behind that, technical or otherwise.

Not allowed characters: `OIl0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been adopted mainly due to ambiguity of some of the characters. Copying from the [source code of Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/66e3b16b8b1033414f843058f360e22b725d89c5/src/base58.h#L7):

Why base-58 instead of standard base-64 encoding?

- Don't want 0OIl characters that look the same in some fonts and could be used to create visually identical looking data.
- A string with non-alphanumeric characters is not as easily accepted as input.
- E-mail usually won't line-break if there's no punctuation to break at.
- Double-clicking selects the whole string as one word if it's all alphanumeric.